# How to store long in a Swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, long-integer, integer-overflow

I got a couple user IDs I want to send in an array, but can't figure out the correct Swift 3 syntax for creating an array with very long integers. I tried casting, `@` prefix and using `as AnyObject`, but that did not work.

```
let idArray = [10211420262370680, 10211420262370680]
```

> Error: integer literal overflows when stored into int

**What is the correct way to create an array with such long integers?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
let idArray: [UInt64] = [10_211_420_262_370_680, ...]
```

As a back of the envelope calculation, every *10 bits* buys you *3 decimal digits*. For instance, `UInt32` maxes out around `4_000_000_000` and so on.

By the way, the underscores `_` above are [just syntax sugar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/integer-literal) for big number literals ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Signed long's array:

```
let signed64BitIntegerArray: [Int64] =      [-10211420262370680, 10211420262370680]
```

Unsigned long's array:

```
let unsigned64BitIntegerArray: [UInt64] =   [ 10211420262370680, 10211420262370680]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need C interop/FFI, use [`CLong`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/clong) or [`CUnsignedLong`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cunsignedlong).